# Generate Values According to Vector in Data Frame

Tags: r, sorting, auto-generate

I have the following data frame
[data frame][1]

Now what I'd like to do is to generate a additional vector with significance codes according to the values in the vector p (p-values for each estimate). Is there a way R can generate a vector filled with stars (as significance) according to the info from an other vector?
And furthermore: is there a way I can tell R, that it should reorganize the data frame according to a new order of observations (I would like to have the following order: vol_s, vol_s_avg, vol_s_med, vol_s_end, vol_l and so on)?

structure of df

```
structure(list(id = c("vol_avg_cer", "vol_avg_cer",     "vol_avg_cer","vol_avg_cer", "vol_cer", "vol_cer"), type = c("partial", "partial", 
"full", "full", "partial", "partial"), parm = c("vol_s_avg", 
"vol_l_avg", "vol_s_avg", "vol_l_avg", "vol_s", "vol_l"), estimate =     c(-0.00419972506246416, 
-0.0199988264598171, -0.0429143892387528, 0.0367191277063419, 
-0.0180348542378266, -0.0825424096818213), stderr = c(0.00729095969265321, 
0.00950796168366169, 0.0296902477909246, 0.052772355386909,     0.0280972492739437, 
0.0458807583546288), p = c(0.564602918461653, 0.0354328407781613, 
0.148344569863659, 0.486552631437604, 0.520955910904793, 0.0720085952786877
)), .Names = c("id", "type", "parm", "estimate", "stderr", "p"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 20L, 21L, 1825L, 1826L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share your data in a format we can import it to R?

Comment: @TARehman did not know exactly how to do this, but I hope it works with the CSV code?!

Comment: copy the output of `dput(df)` (or `dput(head(df))` if there is too much data)

Comment: @tospig is that of more help?

Comment: Yes - now people can use your data directly.

Comment: @tospig the below code helped a lot (mutate). but unfortunately the column signif is not in the df (respectively does appear in the console but not in the preview). do you know how i add it to the df?
furthermore, is there a way to sort observations (rows) according to an order of my choice?
thanks!

Comment: @tospig i solved the first problem. now i only have to order the observations.

Comment: @CharlieLrue did my answer help?

Comment: @tospig I will test it tomorrow. Unfortunately I do not have access to the files yet. I will give you a feedback as soon as I tried it out. Beforehand, cordial thanks for your help!

Comment: @tospig Thank you so much! Everything worked smoothly!

Comment: no problem; you should accept an answer by selecting the 'tick' by the one that answers your question. This lets others know it's been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @user2802241 's answer of using `dplyr` and `symnum`, to order the `parm` column you can define the the order of the column as a separate vector, then set the `parm` column as a factor using the vector as its levels, and `arrange` on that.

e.g.

```
library(dplyr)

## define a vector with the variables in the order you require
factor_levels <- c("vol_s", "vol_s_avg", "vol_s_med","vol_s_end", "vol_l", "vol_l_avg", "vol_l_med", "vol_l_end")


## stay within dplyr - convert 'parm' to a factor and arrange on it
df <- df %>%
  mutate(signif = symnum(p, 
                         cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.5, 1), 
                         symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")),
         parm = factor(parm, levels = factor_levels)) %>%
  arrange(parm)

> df
           id    type      parm     estimate      stderr          p signif
1     vol_cer partial     vol_s -0.018034854 0.028097249 0.52095591       
2 vol_avg_cer partial vol_s_avg -0.004199725 0.007290960 0.56460292       
3 vol_avg_cer    full vol_s_avg -0.042914389 0.029690248 0.14834457      .
4     vol_cer partial     vol_l -0.082542410 0.045880758 0.07200860      *
5 vol_avg_cer partial vol_l_avg -0.019998826 0.009507962 0.03543284     **
6 vol_avg_cer    full vol_l_avg  0.036719128 0.052772355 0.48655263      .
```

---

If you want to keep the parm column as a `character` you can convert it back

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(signif = symnum(p, 
                     cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.5, 1), 
                     symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")),
     parm = factor(parm, levels = factor_levels)) %>%
arrange(parm) %>%
mutate(parm = as.character(parm))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert numbers to symbols using `symnum`:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, signif = symnum(
  p, cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.5, 1), 
  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")))
```